# Force no BOM when saving XML

Tags: c#, xml, byte-order-mark, textwriter

I'm saving a XML file that is used by an external tool.
The tool sadly doesn't understand the encoding BOM (Byte Order Mark: `EF BB BF`) at the beginning of the file:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...

00000000h: EF BB BF 3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65 72 73 69 6F 6E   ï»¿<?xml version
00000010h: 3D 22 31 2E 30 22 20 65 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3D   ="1.0" encoding=
00000020h: 22 55 54 46 2D 38 22 3F 3E ...                    "UTF-8"?>
```

My code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
// Stuff...
using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, false, Encoding.UTF8)) {
    doc.Save(sw);
}
```

**Question:**
How do I force the TextWriter to NOT write the BOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a [`UTF8Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.aspx) instance which doesn't use the BOM, instead of using `Encoding.UTF8`.

```
using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, false, new UTF8Encoding(false))) {
    doc.Save(sw);
}
```

You can save this in a static field if you're worried about the cost of instantiating it repeatedly:

```
private static readonly Encoding UTF8NoByteOrderMark = new UTF8Encoding(false);

...

using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file, false, UTF8NoByteOrderMark)) {
    doc.Save(sw);
}
```

Comment: I'm impressed - detailed answer in less than two minutes. You would certainly be the bearer of the `Burning Keyboard` gold badge!